# Sprinkler system spraying water at the main pipe. How bad is this?

Tags: sprinkler-system

How bad is this leak will the whole pipe need to be replaced?[image]

Comment: Kind of hard to see what exactly is going on here. Looks like the pipe may have split (possibly due to freezing?). If so, your choices are replace the pipe or patch it. You might be able to use one of those fiberglass/epoxy tape patch products.

Comment: The fact that it happened this time of year suggests freeze damage. People only think some places don't freeze. Anywhere in the continental US can freeze, ask any Texan!

Answer (score 1):

That leak is not good.  If you pay for water it is a waste of your money.

Turn off the shut off valve for that system.

Cannot see below the black covering, but imagine you just need to replace that piece of pipe, not the whole section/length.

Do you have cold/freezing temperatures in your area?  It looks like it was caused by freezing.